# How do you move through multiple forms on one html request?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am not sure if I am asking this question correctly. Please let me know if it is not clear and I can providing clarifying information.

The intended behaviour is:

1) user press submit button and generate request through form A/html A (request = ...POST '/user_info/') and calls function B

2) this leads the user to form B/html B to enter more information (same url) (request = ...POST '/user_info/')

3) then user is redirected to the next url

Reaching form B depends on the input of A.  Also, I want to iterated over form B (same template) multiple times but the exact number of times is unknown.

My def looks like this.

```
def function B
...
return render(request(?), b.html, {'form': form B})
```

The issue I am facing is at step 2. The behavior is that once you hit submit on formA, the page returns to form A/html A. It never gets to Form B/html B, even though printing variable in function_B shows that all the variables have the correct values.  Do I need to change the request to direct it to the right page?

Here is example for more concrete help:

view.py

```
def view_function1(request):
    form = FormA
    ### more code

    if User_input = certain specification
        results = function_C(data, request)
        ### more code
    return render(request, a.html, {'form': form})

def function_C(data, request):
    results = function_B([q['choices'] for q in List, request)
    return results

def function_B(choice, request)
    form = formB(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid()
            answer = form.cleaned_data['answer']
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('viewA'))
    return render(request, 'b.html', {'form': form, 'choice': choice})
```

Here is the form:

```
class FormB(forms.Form):
    answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Answer'}), label="")
```

Comment: Does your form B data depend on form A? Or they are just two separate steps?

Comment: @ShangWang. If Form B depends on the input of Form A. One additional note, I don't know how many steps there are, so I'm not sure if form wizard can help.

Comment: From the code that you posted I cannot see what the problem might be. Please post the full Django endpoint  and the form header

Comment: @Geo Jacob. I was wondering if you can take a look at this issue.